# Upgrade kernel to linux-4.4.53

Tags: kernel

I'm using elementary OS Loki 0.4. 
It uses the 4.4.0-66-generic kernel.

I very recently started kernel module programming and am unable to run my Makefile because apparently the complete kernel is not installed.

The tutorial suggests installing a new kernel from the tarball.

The latest 4.4 kernel available is linux-4.4.53.
If I install it from the tarball, I know the kernel will be upgraded but will all the drivers continue working just as they do now?

I'm a bit reluctant because while using elementary OS Freya 0.3, in a similar fashion I had upgraded my kernel to current latest stable version 4.10.2 and had lost all my USB, Ethernet and WiFi drivers.

Just want to make sure that the same won't happen this time.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to install the kernel source package from elementary OS, otherwise there is always a risk of a driver problem.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-generic
apt-get source linux-image-generic
```

You can use another version of the linux kernel, of course.